# How to find and replace substrings at the end of column headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following columns, among others, in my dataframe: dom_pop', 'an_dom_n', 'an_dom_ncmplt. Equivalent columns exist in multiple dataframes, with the suffix changing. For example, in another dataframe they may be called out as pa_pop', 'an_pa_n', 'an_pa_ncmplt. I want to append '_kwh' to these cols across all my dataframes.

I wrote the following code:

```
cols = ['_n$', '_ncmplt', '_pop'] << the $ is added to indicate string ending in _n.
filterfuel = 'kwh'
for c in cols:
    dfdom.columns = [col.replace(f'{c}', f'{c}_{filterfuel}') for col in dfdom.columns]
    dfpa.columns = [col.replace(f'{c}', f'{c}_{filterfuel}') for col in dfpa.columns]
    dfsw.columns = [col.replace(f'{c}', f'{c}_{filterfuel}') for col in dfsw.columns]
```

kwh gets appended to _ncmplt and _pop cols, but not the _n column. If I remove the $ _n gets appended but then _ncmplt looks like 'an_dom_n_kwh_cmplt'.

for df dom the corrected names should look like dom_pop_kwh', 'an_dom_n_kwh', 'an_dom_ncmplt_kwh'

Why is $ not being recongnised as an end of string parameter?

Comment: `for col in dfdom.columns` is iterating over each column. Each value from columns is a python `str`. Making the function used python [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) which just does exact substring replacement without regex. You're either looking for [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) or [Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `regex=True`.

Comment: wouldn't str.replace replace text in the data instead of the column headers? I'm relatively new at python.  Can you give me an example on how to write it? thx

Comment: Something like `import re` `dfdom.columns = [re.sub(f'{c}', f'{c}_{filterfuel}', col) for col in dfdom.columns]` or `dfdom.columns = dfdom.columns.str.replace(f'{c}', f'{c}_{filterfuel}', regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` with a regex

```
cols = ['_n$', '_ncmplt', '_pop']
filterfuel = 'kwh'

pattern = fr"(?:{'|'.join(cols)})"

for df in [dfdom, dfpa, dfsw]:
    df.columns = np.where(df.columns.str.contains(pattern, regex=True),
                          df.columns + f"_{filterfuel}", df.columns)
```

Output:

```
>>> pattern
'(?:_n$|_ncmplt|_pop)'


# dfdom = pd.DataFrame([[0]*4], columns=['dom_pop', 'an_dom_n', 'an_dom_ncmplt', 'hello'])
# After:
>>> dfdom
   dom_pop_kwh  an_dom_n_kwh  an_dom_ncmplt_kwh  hello
0            0             0                  0      0
```